# Oracle AWR text or html extraction to csv

Tags: python, oracle, csv, logging, awr

I received an Oracle AWR Report, statistics fold under text and lst extensions.
Is there a way I can read or parse these into a csv ? read them in Python?
I asked for an another HTML extraction. Could you please share a snippet to read html AWR?

I can't seem to manage to read the .lst reports.

Comment: What do you mean by "statistics fold", "lst extensions", and ".lst reports"? There are [many options](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.html) for getting AWR reports, and the data can also be directly retrieved from `DBA_HIST*` tables. While most DBAs use shell scripts to generate reports, they can be retrieved with SQL like `SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.AWR_REPORT_HTML(L_DBID => X, L_BID => Y, L_EID => Z));` The results could be read and transformed using `XMLTABLE`. But we need to know exactly what data you want.

Comment: The issue is not getting an AWR Report. In my organisation, that is not my job. However the DB teams reached out so I perform extra analysis on the SQL queries which consume a lot of CPU.
For this pupose, I received the reports (SQL ordered by Elapsed Time) in text format and in lst extention. FYI: : A file with an .lst extension is most likely a text file that contains a list of data separated by line breaks. 
I would like to read these in python for the analysis solely.  Since I couldn't read the lst files nor transform the txt report to csv, I asked for an HTML Extract.